# How to create an exe that will start both tomcat and web browser when we click on it?

Tags: tomcat, browser

How to create an exe that will start both tomcat and web browser when we click on it? i.e. I want to create an exe that will contain startup.bat and Google chrome exe. And after starting execution it should start tomcat as well as google chrome.
I tried this on AutoIt.And written the following script

```
Run("C:\softwares\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\bin\startup.bat")
```

But after executing this code tomcat is not getting started, it is just displaying the command prompt for few seconds and then disappearing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried AutoIT Scripts? Mostly they are used for malware, but it can also be used constructively. If you have the whole code in a `.bat` file, then you can use [AutoIT Script](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/).

For executing the batch of starting your web server, mysql server and google chrome, you can use this code:

```
Run("apache2 /init")
Run("mysql -d")
Run("chrome")
WinWait("Google Chrome")
```

Or, as you said you have a `startup.bat` file with you, you can use this code:

```
Run("startup.bat")
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: No I have not used  AutoIT Scripts. But I am not sure whether that will help me or not,cause I just want to put these two files in one exe and after clicking on this exe, execution of both of them should start.

Comment: @user1358548 Yeah, this will be converted into EXE file and when you execute it, it will open Tomcat Server, MySQL Server, and Google Chrome. You can check about that more in that link.

Comment: It is opening the browser but tomcat is not getting started, it is just showing the command prompt for few seconds and then disappearing.

Comment: @user1358548 I mean, did you use the right batch file to start?

Comment: Yes I am using the right batch file.The same batch file is running independently.

Comment: I don't understand your problem. When you try running the `.bat` file independently, were you able to run the server? After converting to `.exe`, it is not running. Is it so?

Comment: Yes. And I am not getting what is the problem.

Comment: @user1358548, when you execute an AutoIT Script, it normally executes from %temp%. I guess that should be the problem. So, try renavigating to the right path. For Eg., if you are in C:\Tomcat\Bin\tomcat.exe and the Batch file is in C:\ with contents `Tomcat\Bin\tomcat.exe`, this doesn't work. So, you need to renavigate by giving `C:`, `CD \ `.

Comment: So I should navigate the bat file to C:\ is this what you are trying to say? I am not getting you.

Comment: In your batch file, please give absolute path, like from the drive... i.e., instead of `bin\tomcat.exe` give as `C:\Tomcat\bin\tomcat.exe` got it?

Comment: I have given the entire path , and as I said earlier it is showing the command prompt for few seconds and then disappearing.

Comment: Okay, in that case, give this as last line and let me know the output.
`pause` so that we can be sure that there are no errors in the batch file and is not prematuredly getting closed...

Comment: Still its not working. Now it is not even showing command prompt. I think the problem is, the command prompt is getting closed before complete execution.In such case how to check if it is closing before complete execution?

Comment: Okay... Can you post the full code of the .bat file and autoit script?

Comment: Run("C:\softwares\apache-tomcat-6.0.35\bin\startup.bat")     This is the autoit script

Comment: This should actually work! I am not sure why it is not working.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have never used AutoIt. And now I just used it and got the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Finally it worked...Actually it was showing message on command prompt but as I said the command prompt was displaying for few seconds so I was not able to read the message. But the message was

```
CATALINA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
environment variable is needed to run this program.
```

and when I set the variable it starts working.